# Best way to create table from list of objects in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to create html table from list of objects.
For example, I have list of **person** objects:

```
[{name: aaa, surname : ssss}, {name: nnn, surname : rrrr}....]
```

and I want to have `html` table looks like this:

```
    |Name|Surname|
    |aaaa|sssss  |
    |nnnn|rrrr   |
```

What is the best way to do this?

`AngularJs` has got a `ngRepeate` directive which allows to create table quickly and comfortably. Has `Dojo` got any similar way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dojo DataGrid to populate/render a table from your object;

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html

So the syntax would look somewhat like below;

```
 var grid = new DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        structure: layout
    });
```

You can have your list of person objects passed as "structure" parameter to the DataGrid
i.e.

```
layout = [{name: aaa, surname : ssss}, {name: nnn, surname : rrrr}....]
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use dgrid. It's well supported and maintained. Here you have an example how to [create the grid from JSON](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/hello_dgrid/). There are also plenty of demos how to configure the dgrid component on a page to show various types of data (e.g. join some rows or columns together).

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer to this question is : no, there is nothing like angular's ng-repeat in dojo, at least not in the html side of things. The closest you can get to do that is, as Amiramix mentioned, dgrid. But its usage is a bit more involved than a simple angular ng-repeat.

It's probably overkill if you just want to do a simple html table, but it brings lots of useful features to your table if you need a more powerful one. So it may be worth a try depending on your use case. There is a comprehensive tutorial at [dgrid.io](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/) if you want to go beyond rendering a static view of a few rows of data.

Now, it all depends on the overall architecture of your app (if you use an MVC framework you probably have a template engine that does exactly what you need, regardless you use dojo or not. From your question, we don't really know what else than dojo you use).